# How to handle access token?

Tags: android, json, gridview, getjson

I am novice android developer and developing `app` for the first time so please be gentle if i am making any mistake in asking question.

I have `API` Document which is attached (Consist of Access Token)  and i want to call category Using `GetCateogry` method as stated in the `APIdocument` also want to display the Category in the `Gridview`.

I have tried different methods but enable to figure out how to display the `Json` Response to `GridView`. I am bit confuse about how to handle Access token using GET & Post method.

Any help would be Highly Appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Postman showing Getcategory

[image: image1]

API Dcoument

[image: image2]

Access Token

[image: image3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a library like [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) to manage your network requests (which I highly recommend), you could easily add the token as header to your request with:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();  
httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {  
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request original = chain.request();

        // Request customization: add request headers
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
            .header("Authentication", "accessToken"); // <-- this is the important line

        Request request = requestBuilder.build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
});

OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
```

Check out this [tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-manage-request-headers-in-okhttp-interceptor) for further reading.

Comment: @ Marius Thanks for your prompt response.

Can you please let me know how can i display the result into the gridview.

Comment: With Retrofit you can parse the response into objects and then pass them to your `GridView`'s adapter. Just search for Retrofit2 tutorials, there are many (e.g. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html). How to display your data in the `GridView` check out https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html